# Using std::conditional with non-convertible types (raw vs pointer)

Tags: c++, c++11, templates, template-meta-programming, sfinae

I am trying to write a class template that chooses to store a member variable raw or as a pointer depending on a `MAX_SIZE` template argument.
When I try to instantiate it with a `MAX_SIZE` large enough that it chooses raw, the compiler still tries to compile the line where I assign the value as a pointer and triggers an impossible conversion error - even though it would probably optimize this line out at some point.

```
template <int MAX_SIZE = sizeof(void*)>
class WeakVar {
    typedef typename std::conditional<sizeof(long double) <= MAX_SIZE, long double, long double*>::type TypeLD;
    TypeLD ld_;

public:
    WeakVar() {
        if(std::is_pointer<TypeLD>::value)
            ld_ = new long double(0); // error: cannot convert 'long double*' to 'TypeLD'{aka 'long double'}
        else
            ld_ = 0;
    }
    //...
};
```

The class is meant to be a space-efficient "weak typed variable" (not necessarily speed-efficient, it's not meant to be called often). The 'ld_' member is actually part of a union (along with a `char`, an `int`, a `bool`, a `float`, etc...).

I tried making setters with `std::enable_if`, but to no avail...

```
//...
WeakVar() { setLD(0); }

typename std::enable_if<std::is_pointer<TypeLD>::value>::type setLD(long double value) {
    ld_ = new long double(value);
}
typename std::enable_if<!std::is_pointer<TypeLD>::value>::type setLD(long double value) {
    ld_ = value;
}
// error: the second method cannot be overloaded with the first
//...
```

Is there a way to achieve this? (while keeping the possibility to choose the `MAX_SIZE` of the class)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that when you write

```
WeakVar() {
    if(std::is_pointer<TypeLD>::value)
        ld_ = new long double(0); // error: cannot convert 'long double*' to 'TypeLD'{aka 'long double'}
    else
        ld_ = 0;
}
```

the compiler has to compile **both** cases of the `if()`

So also when a `TypeLD` isn't a pointer, the compiler has to compile

```
 ld_ = new long double(0);
```

Solution: if (when) you can use C++17 or newer, use `if constexpr`

```
    if constexpr (std::is_pointer<TypeLD>::value)
        ld_ = new long double(0);
    else
        ld_ = 0;
```

that is introduced exactly to not compile the wrong code when the value of the test is compile-time known.

Otherwise (in C++11 and C++14) you can write two different functions and, using SFINAE, enable the correct one.

By example (caution: code not tested)

```
template <typename T = TypeLD,
          typename std::enable_if<true == std::is_pointer<T>::value, bool>::type = true>
WeakVar () : ld_{new long double(0)}
 { }

template <typename T = TypeLD,
          typename std::enable_if<false == std::is_pointer<T>::value, bool>::type = true>
WeakVar () : ld_{0}
 { }
```

> I tried making setters with std::enable_if, but to no avail...

This is because SFINAE, to enable/disable a method of a class, works only with template methods with tests over template parameters of the method itself, not over template parameter of the class.

So, in the example above, I've written

```
template <typename T = TypeLD,
          typename std::enable_if<true == std::is_pointer<T>::value, bool>::type = true>
```

so the enabling/disabling test is about a typename `T`, template parameter of the constructor, not about `TypeLD`, template parameter of the full class.

If you write

```
template <typename std::enable_if<true == std::is_pointer<TypeLD>::value, bool>::type = true>
```

you get an error.

Comment: In the `enable_if` why write `true == std::is_pointer<T>::value` instead of just `std::is_pointer<T>::value`? Likewise in the `false` case it could just be `!std::is_pointer<T>::value`.

Comment: @Kyle - It's a problem of mine: I find very difficult see, at a glance, the difference between `condition` and `!condition`. I find it's very clearer and more immediate see the difference explicating `true` and `false`.

Answer (score 1):

A much simpler solution would be to provide a different base class differentiated by `std::conditional`:

```
class WeakVarA {};
class WeakVarB {};

template <int MAX_SIZE = sizeof(void*)>
class WeakVar 
    : public typename std::conditional<sizeof(long double) <= MAX_SIZE, WeakVarA, WeakVarB>::type 
{
    // ...
};
```

Then simply implement `WeakVarA` as a dynamic and `WeakVarB` as a non-dynamic approach or vice-versa.

Answer (score 1):

This little utility:

```
#define RETURNS(...) \
  noexcept(noexcept(__VA_ARGS__)) \
  -> decltype(__VA_ARGS__) \
  { return __VA_ARGS__; }

template<class S, class F0, class...Fs>
auto dispatch( std::integral_constant<S, S(0)>, F0&& f0, Fs&&... )
RETURNS( dispatch( std::forward<F0>(f0) ) )

template<class S, S s, class F0, class...Fs>
auto dispatch( std::integral_constant<S, s>, F0&&, Fs&&...fs )
RETURNS( dispatch( std::integral_constant<S, S(s-1)>{}, std::forward<Fs>(fs)... ) )

template<std::size_t N, class...Fs>
auto dispatch( Fs&&...fs )
RETURNS( dispatch( std::integral_constant<std::size_t, N>{}, std::forward<Fs>(fs)... ) )
```

can help.

It does a compile-time switch.

```
WeakVar() {
    ld_ = dispatch(std::is_pointer<TypeLD>{}, []{ return 0.; }, []{ return new long double(0); } )();
}
```

dispatch, when called with a compile-time constant `std::integral_constant<T, t>`, returns its nth argument.  If you pass it `std::true_type`, that is `std::integral_constant<bool, true>`.

`std::is_pointer<T>` inherits from either `true_type` or `false_type`.

We then pass dispatch 2 lambdas.  At compile time one is picked.  We then run the return value.  It then returns either a double, or a pointer to a double.

As which one is returned is determined at compile time, this works fine.

In [c++14](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b14) and [c++17](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b17) this gets much easier, but I work with what I got.  And dispatch works really well to solve this kind of problem in [c++11](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b11).